# Regex - is this nesting or recursion - or even possible?

Tags: c#, regex

Can anyone help me with a regex expression to solve this:

```
[x: {aaa}] blablabla [x: {bbb}, {ccc}] blablabla [y: {ddd}]
```

**required:** aaa bbb ccc

i.e. look for `[x: ]` then get the text in curly brackets - and ignore anything in `[y: ]`

Is it even possible?

Comment: It depends on the regex flavor. Best way is to use a 2 step approach rather than try using [`(?:\[x:|(?!^)\G)(?:\s*|\},\s*)\{\K[^}]+`](https://regex101.com/r/eL7sG0/2).

Comment: I'm in C# - I don't think I can use `\K` - I'm not even sure what it's for!

Comment: In C#, it is even easier, you do not need regex :) Or a very simple one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you can use a non-regex approach (if your data is always well-formatted):

```
var s = "[x: {aaa}] blablabla [x: {bbb}, {ccc}] blablabla [y: {ddd}]";
var res = s.Split('[', ']')          // Split with `[` and `]`
   .Where(q => q.StartsWith("x: "))  // Only get those elements starting with x:
   .SelectMany(m => m.Trim().Substring(4, m.Length - 5).Split(new[] { "}, {" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
   .ToList();                        // Convert to a List<string> all the elements
```

[image]

**A regex is preferable if the data is not always well-formatted**. Here is one you can use:

```
@"\[x:\s*{(?<val>[^}]*)}(?:\s*,\s*{(?<val>[^}]*)})*"
```

Breakdown:

- `\[x:\s*` - a sequence of characters `[x:` followed with 0+ whitespace(s)
- `{(?<val>[^}]*)}` - a `{...}` substring the inner part of which is *captured* into a named capture group named "val" (it has a stack for all the values captured accessible via `Match.Groups["val"].Captures`)
- `(?:\s*,\s*{(?<val>[^}]*)})*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `\s*,\s*` - 0+ whitespaces followed with a comma and again 0+ whitespaces
  - `{(?<val>[^}]*)}` - same as above, adding more values to the "val" group stack.

**NOTE that "val" cannot contain `}` in this case.** See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5Bx%3A%5Cs*%7B(%3F%3Cval%3E%5B%5E%7D%5D*)%7D(%3F%3A%5Cs*%2C%5Cs*%7B(%3F%3Cval%3E%5B%5E%7D%5D*)%7D)*&i=%5Bx%3A%20%7Baaa%7D%5D%20blablabla%20%5Bx%3A%20%7Bbbb%7D%2C%20%7Bccc%7D%5D%20blablabla%20%5By%3A%20%7Bddd%7D%5D), just grab the *`match.Groups["val"].Captures`*.

```
var s = "[x: {aaa}] blablabla [x: {bbb}, {ccc}] blablabla [y: {ddd}]";
var res = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[x:\s*{(?<val>[^}]*)}(?:\s*,\s*{(?<val>[^}]*)})*")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .SelectMany(p => p.Groups["val"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(m => m.Value))
        .ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: That works a treat. I hadn't thought of a regex/linq mix! neat!

Comment: Now ... is it possible in Javascript too :)

Comment: It will require some code. Try your hand at it since now you have an idea how it can be done in C#.